# GOOGLE DATA STUDIO BIG QUERY count distinct aggregation IS NOT WORKING

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

When I select CTD as an aggregation in Google Data Studio using BigQuery as the database I am having a big problem.
This need to be fixed as soon as possible. Is extremely important.

Here an Image with the result of Count Distinct in Bigquery

https://prnt.sc/ll2r4n

Here an Image with the result of APROX COUNT DISTINCT

https://prnt.sc/ll2swm

GOOGLE DATA STUDIO is sending APROX COUNT DISTINCT when I am selecting CTD aggregation in google data studio.

Is a big problem because the report is not useful. Sometimes when the value>1000 the result of the APROX COUNT DISTINCT is not correct. We need count Distinct no APROX to deliver reports with accuracy to our clients.

More info: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/forums/v3_1/forumtopicpage/board-id/Data-Studio/thread-id/2091/highlight/true/page/1

Almost two years from that post and no news....

Comment: Given that restriction, can't you create the correct dataset you need in BigQuery first and link your reports to that?

Comment: Of course, I can. But every time I need to generate a CTD  in a metric I will need to create a new dataset? Is not a solution.

Comment: I am expecting an answer with a deadline on this of the Google Team.

Comment: Then I'd suggest voting for the issue on here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72937416

Comment: Thanks we are doing that. I hope we have a answer soon.

Comment: You certainly seem to have got the votes rolling in!

Answer (score 0):

Data Studio has updated COUNT_DISTINCT to perform an exact distinct count.

Now you're in control of which is more critical on a case-by-case basis: exactness or performance.

The [APPROXIMATE_COUNT_DISTINCT](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9189108) takes one parameter, which can be the name of a metric, dimension, or expression of any type to perform a faster approximate distinct count.

Please note that over data sources other than BigQuery, APPROXIMATE_COUNT_DISTINCT is equivalent to COUNT_DISTINCT.